# "ssh connect to host x port y: No route to host" after reboot when fail2ban is active on a different port than 22

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I have this error when I install fail2ban on my server and when the ssh port is different from 22.

It's an almalinux distribution. I already set semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp {{ var_ssh_port }} for selinux to accept a different port than 22. I also put it in rc.local in case selinux doesnt keep the change after reboot.

I am managing fail2ban with a ansible playbook. I tried with two different ansible playbook and it's the same after reboot : i get this ssh error "no route to host"

The error doesnt occur if i keep the ssh port on 22 and i can connect before reboot when fail2ban is active.

I dont see where to investigate to try things out.

Thank you

Comment: Did you change sshd_config port?

Comment: yes it is matched to the variable var_ssh_port